# Desktop icons appear rapidly

Tags: macos, windows, graphics, bug

You have to watch video to get the point because I cant explain this:

[VIDEO](https://streamable.com/rk6jul)

So I am changing desktops with "three fingers swipe" gesture on touchpad.

This problem appeared recently, because I do remember as the icons were in place while I been switching desktops.

How to fix it? How to make desktop icons appear instantly?

Comment: I don't see a problem. Does it just 'look different' that what you are used to? Does it cause any problems in the long run?

Comment: @IconDaemon Not actually, but it looks terrible.

Comment: You do know that you didn't actually ask a question?  As you wrote it most likely is a bug.  I've just observed the same with the menu bar (always meant to be visible in my setup).  Playing with the menu bar settings then returned it to the normal(?) behaviour, i.e. it's there all along between full screen and Desktop swipes.

Comment: @Redarm Already fixed!